# Use a regular expression to find some specific text

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to extract specific tags from a text file (source code in this case). I've tried many ways, but none of them has been successful.

For example, this is the file:

```
//messagebox("ñ",string(asc("ñ")))
//messagebox("Ñ",string(asc("Ñ")))
//messagebox("ñ",string(char(241)))

messagebox("Hi")

IF Trim(sle_user_id.text) = "" AND Trim(sle_password.text) = "" THEN
    MessageBox(Titulo_Msg,&
              "Sr Usuario :~r~nDebe ingresar los datos solicitados.",StopSign!,Ok!)
    sle_user_id.SetFocus()
    Return
End If
```

I need to extract (either on the screen or to a file) the text that is inside the parenthesis in the tag `"messagebox(THIS IS WHAT A I NEED TO EXTRACT)"`

The problems are:

- For this case `[**messagebox("ñ",string(asc("ñ")))**]` shows a truncated word, it ends at the first closing parenthesis: `**("ñ",string(asc("ñ"**`
- For this case `[      **MessageBox(Titulo_Msg,&
                "Sr Usuario :~r~nDebe ingresar los datos solicitados.",StopSign!,Ok!)** ]` shows only the match in the line, but not the complete text between the parenthesis: `**MessageBox(Titulo_Msg,&**`

I have tried using `awk`, `grep`, `sed` and `bash` without success.

Comment: Simple parsers would shine more then regexes here... is that an option?

Comment: Can messagebox() appear multiple times on a line, e.g. `messagebox("Hello"); messagebox("World")`? Can it be followed by something else with parens, e.g. `messagebox("Hello"); // nice :-)`

Comment: Simple parser it's an option, mmm but really i don't have a clue how to do that.

And, yes, it would be an option that `messagebox("Hello"); // nice :-)` appears twice on the same line, but if there is a match of this kind it would be treated like an abnormal case, ignoring it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/[mM]essage[bB]ox\(/,/\)$/ {gsub(/.*[mM]essage[Bb]ox\(|\)$/,""); print}' file
```

Output:

```
"ñ",string(asc("ñ))
"Ñ",string(asc("Ñ))
"ñ",string(char(24))
"Hi
Titulo_Msg,&
              "Sr Usuario :~r~nDebe ingresar los datos solicitados.",StopSign!,Ok
```

Extracts everything in between `messagebox(...)` or `MessageBox(...)` parentheses.

### Note

This would break if there is either text on a line after the final closing `)` or if there were any `)` at the end of a line before the final closing `)` when the content of `MessageBox(...)` spans over multiple lines.

Comment: To the person who downvoted, please leave a comment next time and/or see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this worked fine for just what i wanted:

awk '/[mM]essage[bB]ox\(/,/\)$/ {gsub(/.*[mM]essage[Bb]ox\(|\)$/,""); print}' file

Comment: @CarlosWistubaG. You're welcome, I'm glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers, it helped me so much, this command do the trick exactly just what i wanted:

`awk '/[mM]essage[bB]ox\(/,/\)$/ {gsub(/.*[mM]essage[Bb]ox\(|\)$/,""); print}' file`

Best regards !!
Carlos

Answer (score -1):

No. What you are trying to do requires matching nested parentheses properly and that can not be done via regex.

Unfortunately a finite state machine which a regex is, can not match nested parentheses because it is not context-free.  A more detailed explanation as to why can be found here: [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: That link is for a different use case.  Regex **can** be used to solve the OP's problem given the example text, and it's just wrong to say as a general rule that you can't ever successfully match nested patterns.  A link answer should be a comment.